# Jupyter: "AttributeError: 'Zero' object has no attribute 'name'" error when trying to graph equations on a single graph

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Code:

```py
from sympy import*
from sympy.plotting import (plot, plot_parametric,plot3d_parametric_surface, plot3d_parametric_line,plot3d)

y=symbols('y')
x=symbols('x')
equation = (y*(y**2-1)*(y-2) -(x*(x-1)*(x-2)))

from __future__ import division
from sympy.plotting import plot
p1 = plot_implicit(equation,(x,-5,5), show=False)
p2 = plot(1/3*x+2, (x,-5,5), show=False)
p3 = plot(-x+1, (x,-5,5), show=False)
p1.extend(p2)
p1.extend(p3)
p1.show()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Zero' object has no attribute 'name'
```

This code worked before. Then I opened it and now it's giving me that error.

Comment: You probably want `x/3` instead of `1/3*x`. `1/3` is an ordinary division of ordinary Python integers, not a SymPy operation.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question runs correctly from the IPython prompt and outputs a nice plot in a separate window without printing any error messages.

Try opening a new notebook in Jupyter. In the upper right corner of the Jupyter browser tab select Python 3 (*New* ▾ -> *Python 3*), then run the same code from the new notebook. In order to show the plot inline, you also need to import matplotlib in Jupyter.

Code:

```py
import matplotlib
from sympy import*
from sympy.plotting import (plot, plot_parametric,plot3d_parametric_surface, plot3d_parametric_line,plot3d)

y=symbols('y')
x=symbols('x')
equation = (y*(y**2-1)*(y-2) -(x*(x-1)*(x-2)))

from __future__ import division
from sympy.plotting import plot
p1 = plot_implicit(equation,(x,-5,5), show=False)
p2 = plot(1/3*x+2, (x,-5,5), show=False)
p3 = plot(-x+1, (x,-5,5), show=False)
p1.extend(p2)
p1.extend(p3)
p1.show()
```

Plot:

[image]